# How can this integral be solved? Is is an indefinite integral?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> The integral I want to solve is $$\int_1^2 \frac {2 \ln(x)}{x+1} dx$$

I tried to integrate it by parts in 2 ways and I tried to do the integral by parts twice, I thought of a change of variable and they all didn't work.

Can any one help by giving a solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral evaluates to,
$$2(\ln (2)\ln (3) + \operatorname{Li}_2 (-2) + \frac {π^2}{12})$$
Use the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts),
$$\int (f.g') dx = f.g - \int (f'.g) dx$$
And the definition of [dilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) to get your result.
Assume $f(x):=\ln x$ and $g'(x):=\frac {1}{1+x}$ and substitute $z:=-x$.
$$\operatorname{Li}_2 := \int \frac {\ln (1-t)}{t} dt$$

Comment: @Fareed AF, the dilogarithm $Li_2$ is a special function like $\log (x)$ and $e^x$ , it has its own series representation and identities. Read it here:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function

Comment: Thank you :-), I appreciate your help